# background image dynamically applied using jQuery disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

I have run through about every option for performing a background image change in the body with jQuery and am running into the same thing over and over again.  The background image is there for a flash and disappears.
In the code I have included some javascript alerts to pause the page and the background image is up and looking great at the time the alert is hit, but after I click the ok button to get past the alert, the image goes away.
I was originally using the alerts to make sure I was getting the correct values.  Does anyone know why the background image wouldn't "stick?"
My current code is below - I have tried this with many different code blocks found on the web and all are still failing to change the bg image.  Thanks a lot!

```
var bg1 = "url(/images/bg1.jpg)";
var bg2 = "url(/images/bg2.jpg)";
var bg3 = "url(/images/bg3.jpg)";

$("nav a").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    //alert(id);

    switch (id) {
        case "home":
            $('body').css({ backgroundImage: bg1 });
            //alert("case - home");
            break;
        case "about":
            $('body').css({ backgroundImage: bg2 });
            //alert("case - about");
            break;
        default:
            $('body').css({ backgroundImage: bg3 });
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to guess, the page is reloading, try preventing the default behavior (and if that doesnt work, post a link or something, not enough information here).

Comment: Like Karl said, `$("nav a").click(function (ev) { ev.preventDefault() ...`

Comment: While it is a simple asp.net app, there could likely be something else happening in the .net framework.  Thanks for the responses - I'll have to do more digging.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have errors elsewhere, the problem lies with your CSS property, which should be quoted as a string:

```
var bg1 = "url(/images/bg1.jpg)";
var bg2 = "url(/images/bg2.jpg)";
var bg3 = "url(/images/bg3.jpg)";

$("nav a").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    //alert(id);

    switch (id) {
        case "home":
            $('body').css({ "background-image": bg1 });
            //alert("case - home");
            break;
        case "about":
            $('body').css({ "background-image": bg2 });
            //alert("case - about");
            break;
        default:
            $('body').css({ "background-image": bg3 });
            break;
    }
});
```

All I did was change `backgroundImage` to `"background-image"`.

Comment: Thanks for the updated syntax - I reckon I was using the older syntax.  Sadly, it didn't fix the problem.  :)  I'll have to do a bit more digging.

Comment: Your paths might be problematic as well. See if it helps to remove the forward slash at the beginning of your url paths.

Comment: try 
`$('body').css({ "background-image": "bg1" });`